# Hbase Update/Insert using Get/Put

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

Could anyone advise what would be the best way to go for my requirement.

I have the below

1. An Hbase table
2. An input file in HDFS

My Requirement is as below

1. Read the input file and fetch the key. Using key get the data from
   Hbase.
2. Do a comparison to check.
3. If comparison fails, insert
4. If comparison is successful update.

I know i can use get to fetch the data and put to write it back. Is this the best way to go forward.I hope i will use mapreduce so that i can get the process to run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

HBase has a checkAndPut() and a checkAndDelete() operation. which allows you to perform a put or a delete if you have the value you expect (compare=NO_OP if you don't care about the value but just about the key). 
https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am a bit new to Hbase so was wondering if i put the checkAndPut() in mapreduce ? ,just in case if you have any link that i can refer to that also will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your problem I actually recommend a slightly different approach here. While it probably is feasible to implement HBase puts inside a MapReduce Job, it sounds like a rather complex task.

I'd recommend loading data from HBase into MapReduce joining the two tables and then exporting them back into HBase.
Using Pig this would be rather easy to achieve.
Take a look at [Pig HBaseStorage](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage.html).
Going this route you'd load both files, join them and then write back to HBase. If all there is to it, is comparing keys, this can be achieved in 5 lines of PigLatin.

HTH